# Password protect a page template which gets posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

I've built a template which gets posts from a category and have added this in as i want it to be password protected. It doesn't seem to work and i don't know why.

Is anyone kind enough to help me out?

```
<?php
if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {

$temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('cat=495' . '&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

<div <?php post_class() ?>>
<h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent          Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<div class="entry">
 <?php the_content() ?>
 </div>

 <br>

 </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>

 }else{
// we will show password form here
echo get_the_password_form();
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Silly question, but did you actually password protect the post itself?

Comment: No i haven't password protected the posts as this would be very time consuming. I really wanted the page to be locked and then when you enter the password it displays the posts on from that category. Haven't found any solutions online so far...

Comment: No, what I meant was have you added a password to the "page" this template is running on?  This page is pulling in different posts... But the page itself needs a password...

Comment: Oh yes sorry, i have. When testing the page i get this error message "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/fhlinux221/j/jenningsrugs.co.uk/user/htdocs/pages/wp-content/themes/default/priviledged-customers.php on line 65"

Comment: Well, looks like there is more to this story then!  The code above is not 65 lines worth, so please post the code for the "privileged-customers.php page and I'll be able to find your error.

Comment: I've added it as an answer! Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php
/*
Template Name: Privileged Customers Template
*/

get_header();
?>
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_01.jpg" width="57" height="20"></td>
<td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_02.jpg" width="886" height="20"></td>
<td><img src="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_03.jpg" width="57" height="20"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_04.jpg"><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="57" height="416" /></td>
<td valign="top" background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_05.jpg"><table width="886"   border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="826" height="1" /></td>
      <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="10" /></td>
      <td align="left">
      <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">
 <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <?php do_action('posts_logout_link'); ?>
 <?php
 if ( ! post_password_required( $post ) ) {

 $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null;
 $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('cat=495' . '&paged='.$paged);
 while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

 <div <?php post_class() ?>>
<h3 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent               Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

<div class="entry">
<?php the_content() ?>
 </div>

 <br>

 </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

}else{
// we will show password form here
echo get_the_password_form();
}

?>



  </div>
      </td>
      <td><img src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="30" height="10" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table></td>
<td background="../../../images/blank_middle/blank_middle_06.jpg"><img    src="../../../images/spacer.gif" width="57" height="416" /></td>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

On lines 46-53 of the code you posted, you have:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>

}else{
// we will show password form here
echo get_the_password_form();
}

?>
```

Line 46 you are opening and closing PHP on the same line, then trying to run more PHP after (line 48).  Since you closed PHP and haven't opened it again, the PHP starting on line 48 is being rendered as HTML... therefore your if/else statement is never getting properly closed... hence the `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end` error.

Change line 46 from:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

to:

```
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: Great!  Can you mark my answer as correct so I can get credit?